# Is it possible to remove one specific event handler from an event with multiple handlers?

Tags: jquery

As i searched for the solution of a problem i have right now, i found this thread: [jQuery: more than one handler for same event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491718/jquery-more-than-one-handler-for-same-event). Now i wonder if it is possible to remove just a single one of these handlers?

Comment: For the same event or different events?

Comment: This can't be done easily. You have to do a hack, jQuery wasn't designed for this. use event namespacing instead.

Comment: I think that if you store the event handler in a variable you might be able to remove it the same way you ad it, with the variable, but I have not tested it.

Comment: @Raynos: if I understand the question, you are incorrect - see my answer.

Comment: @MattBall I was thinking anonymous functions. Yes you can unbind a function if you have a pointer to this.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

It is possible, if you **don't** use anonymous callbacks:

```
var $elt = $(...);

function clickHandler1(event){...}
function clickHandler2(event){...}

// bind both
$elt.click(clickHandler1);
$elt.click(clickHandler2);

// unbind just the first
$elt.unbind('click', clickHandler1);
```

[A wild Demo appeared!](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/eWaga/2/)

See also: [`.unbind()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/unbind).

Comment: Wild Demo appeared! :-D

Comment: Note that `bind`, `unbind` is deprecated on v3.0, use `on`, `off` instead.

Answer (score 60):

Actually, you can do it using anonymous callbacks via event namespacing:

```
$elt.bind('click.handler1', function(event) {
    alert('click handler 1');
});

$elt.unbind('click.handler1');
```

See modified demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6r998p2g/).

And [here](http://css-tricks.com/namespaced-events-jquery/) for more information.

This was added in [jQuery 1.4.3](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/), which actually came out more than 4 months before the question was asked.

Comment: can we pass parameters in the function?

Comment: This is a real good answer when using anonymous callback. Loving it.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as most bind/on calls will have an anonymous function.

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer, tried  $(document).on('keydown.fake', function(){}); --->>> $(document).on('keydown.fake');  Haven't noticed event namespaces  in .on() .off() documentation

Comment: One million points to you sir. Just used this to get around a very tricky issue.

Answer (score 4):

This post is ages old, so I thought I'd chime in with how this is done today (2019).

Most of the old answers above, including the accepted answer (which was correct when it was written), use the `unbind` method which has been deprecated since jQuery v.3.0.

> As of jQuery 3.0, .unbind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by
>   the .off() method since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already
>   discouraged.

[Source](https://api.jquery.com/unbind/#unbind-eventType-handler)

Here's how to do it with the `.off()` method:

```
var foo = function() {
  // Code to handle some kind of event
};

// ... Now foo will be called when paragraphs are clicked ...
$( "body" ).on( "click", "p", foo );

// ... Foo will no longer be called.
$( "body" ).off( "click", "p", foo );
```

[Source](https://api.jquery.com/off/)

This will work for all event handlers implemented with the `.on()` method and it works for undelegated event handlers as well. Simply replace "body" with your element selector and remove the second parameter of the `.off()` method ("p" in the example above).