# How to deactivate a nested anonymous function in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('#button-a').click(function(){   
    $('#button-b').click(function(){
        alert('something');
    });
});
$('#button-b').click(function(){   
    // do something
});
```

How can I deactivate the nested #button-b function after I have clicked #button-a, so only the last #button-b function (not nested) activates when i click #button-b and not them both?

Comment: do you mean remove the event? If so you can do $('#button_b').unbind('click')

Comment: However, for this you have to first attach the event like so: $('#button_b').bind('click',function(){});

Comment: @lomas09 no you don't have to.

Comment: You can't specify which function unbind, if it's anonymous. @ http://stackoverflow.com/a/5136424/2180189

Comment: @MightyPork you can do `$(el).off('click')` and then bind the new event, it is situationnal.

Comment: Yes, but not if you want to keep the (possible) other handlers on...

Comment: @MightyPork that's what i said, it is situationnal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using `.on()` and `.off()` event handlers.

```
$('#button-a').click(function(){   
    $('#button-b').off('click');   //unbind the click event of the #button-b
    $('#button-b').click(function(){
        alert('something');
    });
});
$('#button-b').on('click',function(){   
    // do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish this, your function cannot be anonymous. You need to use the form of [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) which specifies the handler to remove. Rewriting your code a bit, it'd look something like this:

```
function myFunc() {
    alert('something');
}

$("#button-a").click(function() {
    $("#button-b").click(myFunc);
});

$("#button-b").click(function() {
    // do something
});
```

To remove the handler, you'd use:

```
$("#button-b").off('click', myFunc);
```

I'm not quite sure *where* you want this to occur, but the above line of code will work anywhere that the DOM has been loaded and `myFunc` is in scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel you definitely need an anonymous handler here, you can use event namespace for your task - http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
    $('#button-b').on('click.nestedClick', function(){
        alert('something');
    });
    // and unbind it at some point:
    $('#button-b').off('click.nestedClick');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button-a').click(function(){   
    $('#button-b').trigger('click');
});
$('#button-b').click(function(){   
    // do something
});
```

Change your code like this so it call your last function for button-b when you click on button-a

Comment: Your wrong, he want to prevent the click event of `#button-b`.  But your code trigger the click. right?

Comment: he just want to call last click of the button and prevent that click so i think this is right