# Closing div reopens again after scrolling

Tags: jquery

I'm making a div appear after another div has scrolled out of view, but the first div has a close button which hides the div. However, when the page is scrolled, the first code fires and reopens the div again.

```
var element = $("#request-consultation").offset().top + $("#request-consultation").outerHeight();
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= element) {
    $("#request-consultation-float").show('slow');
  } else {
    $("#request-consultation-float").hide('slow');
  }
});

$(".request-float-close span").click(function() {       
    $('#request-consultation-float').hide('slow');
});
```

How can I make the `#request-consultation-float` div stay hidden after the `.request-float-close` has been clicked?

Comment: You need to remove the `$(window).scroll(...)` event listener in `$('req span').click(...)`.

Comment: Add a `data-attribute` to your div, and when you the user clicks to close the div simply add a value to the `data-attribute` and then use that to check in your if statement. The problem you are having is when you scroll your `if` statement is returning true so you need to add another condition

Comment: I don't have a window.scroll event in the click event...

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remember the click and behave according to that:

```
var element = $("#request-consultation").offset().top + $("#request-consultation").outerHeight();
var closeClicked = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= element && !closeClicked) {
    $("#request-consultation-float").show('slow');
  } else {
    $("#request-consultation-float").hide('slow');
  }
});

$(".request-float-close span").click(function() {       
    $('#request-consultation-float').hide('slow');
    closeClicked = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a flag variable to check if it is clicked or not like this:

```
var isClicked = false;
var element = $("#request-consultation").offset().top + $("#request-consultation").outerHeight();
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(isClicked) return;
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= element) {
    $("#request-consultation-float").show('slow');
  } else {
    $("#request-consultation-float").hide('slow');
  }
});

$(".request-float-close span").click(function() {       
    $('#request-consultation-float').hide('slow');
    isClicked = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Remove the specific event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136296/is-it-possible-to-remove-one-specific-event-handler-from-an-event-with-multiple):

```
var element = $("#request-consultation").offset().top + $("#request-consultation").outerHeight();

function myCustomScroll() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= element) {
        $("#request-consultation-float").show('slow');
    } else {
        $("#request-consultation-float").hide('slow');
    }
}

$(window).scroll(myCustomScroll);

$(".request-float-close span").click(function() {       
    $('#request-consultation-float').hide('slow');
    $(window).unbind('scroll', myCustomScroll);
});
```

If you don't want to keep a reference to the listener function, you can use [namespacing](https://css-tricks.com/namespaced-events-jquery/):

```
var element = $("#request-consultation").offset().top + $("#request-consultation").outerHeight();

$(window).on('scroll.consultationFloat', function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= element) {
        $("#request-consultation-float").show('slow');
    } else {
        $("#request-consultation-float").hide('slow');
    }
});

$(".request-float-close span").click(function() {       
    $('#request-consultation-float').hide('slow');
    $(window).unbind('scroll.consultationFloat');
});
```

Comment: But what happens if he wants to rebind it at a later date? He shouldn't have to unbind and bind event listeners

Comment: @Canvas That is true, this is just one way to achieve the functionality the OP wants.