# Same signature event handlers in Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Could anyone explain what are the results of defining event handlers with same signature e.g.:

```
// event handler 1
$('form.custom select[data-customforms!=disabled]').on('change', function() { 
    console.log('1');
});

// event handler 2
$('form.custom select[data-customforms!=disabled]').on('change', function() { 
    console.log('2');
});
```

Is it a bad practice? What is the order of execution? Is there any browser specific behavior related to this? Could event handlers in Javascript be extended?

Comment: What is the advantage of doing it?

Comment: [check this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825249/jquery-is-it-illegal-or-bad-practice-to-assign-multiple-event-handlers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result will be that all the attached events will execute in sequence. This is commonly used to execute multiple functions on a particular event.

In the above case, the first `1` will be logged in console, then `2`, just the same order they were applied.

The disadvantage will be that when you remove the `change` event, all the event handlers attached to that event will be removed (in your case, both the handlers with console.log statement)

You can use [event namespacing](http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) to overcome this.

Answer (score 1):

Both handlers will run subsequently.
If you name the handlers, rather than making them anonymous, you can destroy them independently (without the need to completely remove *all* handlers for the 'change' event).

Comment: Cool! How do I define a name for the handler?

Comment: You can check this for event namespacing (I think that's what Kippie meant by saying 'name the handlers')
http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/

Comment: That was indeed what I meant. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery allowing multiple event handler on an element. This means it will not override the older one. I am not sure about the order of execution but it might be random.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery Use **bind** for set event that mean add to event not replace event for replace you must first delete Event then set.