# Event Object is holding previous event properties in Full Calendar

Tags: ajax, fullcalendar

I've got a problem with FullCalendar and I was looking for solution without any success.
I use eventClick to open overlay form with data of current event. Everything works great until I change my mind and don't want to edit this event but another one. And that causes ajax send request 2 times, once for opened event (which was ready to edit but form was not submitted) and once for event which was really edited and submitted.

```
$('#sc-calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventClick: function(event) {   
       //opening overlay form window
              $('#submit-event-update').bind('click',function() { //click submit
                $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "event_update",
                  data: "id="+event.id+"&title="+event.title+"&start="+event.start+"&end="+event.end,
                  cache: false,
                  success: function() {
                    $('#submit-event-update').unbind();
                    $('#sc-calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent',event);
                  }
                });
              });
            }
        });
```

This is starting to be my nightmare. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like there is a problem with the `onclick` event listener for `#submit-event-update`.

You should modify your code in this way:

```
$('#sc-calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventClick: function(event) {

    //opening overlay form window

    //Assign the event id of this event to the global variable event_id
    event_id = event.id;  
    }
});

$('#submit-event-update').bind('click',function() { //click submit
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "event_update",
      data: "id=" + event_id + ..., //Note how event.id is not used anymore
      cache: false,
      success: function() {
         $('#sc-calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent',event);
      }
   });
 });
```

I changed it so that you bind the `onclick` event handler to the button just once as opposed to every time an event is clicked. I also assign a variable `event_id` that holds the value of the current event's id.

Now, for an explanation. You said:

> Everything works great until I change my mind and don't want to edit
>   this event but another one.

What happens when you click on an event?

You bind the `onclick` event to the `#submit-event-update`. Now if you do click the button, then you will go into the `success()` callback of your AJAX call and then unbind the button. But what if you change your mind and don't click the submit button? Now, you have one `onclick` listener with the old data already tied to the button. When you pick another event, you have two event listeners tied to the same button and hence, **an AJAX request is sent two times**.

It might be worth reading up on how JavaScript handles event binding [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491718/jquery-more-than-one-handler-for-same-event).

Comment: This is quite good solution. But if i have another properties which i changed in form it is not changed on calendar or calendar initialization.