# How to bind multiple handlers to same event in jQuery

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I wonder how can I bind several handler functions to same event on a element, for example:

```
$("#this_element").on("click.action1", function(){
/* first thing to run when click this element */
}).on("click.action2", function(){
/* second thing to run when click this element */
}).on("click.action3", function(){
/* last thing to run when click this element */
})
```

Comment: You're binding handlers to events in different namespaces. Did you really intend to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491718/jquery-more-than-one-handler-for-same-event

Comment: @Barmar That is just my guess, I thought when I bind the second one, if I still use same event name string, I will override the existing one.

Comment: No, you can have multiple handlers for the same event. They'll all run, as explained in the linked question.

Comment: @OrestHera Thanks for this. I wonder do u know how to remove certain handler once I bind several handler to same element?

Comment: @Kuan Bind to a named function instead of anonymous function. Then you can use `$("#element").off("click", functionName)`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, but how do you know which function out of all the bind  function has been off?

Comment: You have to keep track of it yourself to know whether you've turned something off.

Answer (score 0):

Just combine them all into one function:

```
$("#this_element").on("click", function() {
    // first thing
    // second thing
    // third thing
});
```

Comment: LOL thanks! The reason I can not do this is because the handling function is conditionally bind to the element, not always three parts together, sometimes I need to bind one of them and remove

Comment: Could you update the question to show the real structure of the code, including the conditionals?

Comment: The reason I did not put real code there is because I am not sure what code should put there, right now, this is just my thinking of design

Comment: Is the conditional really done at the time you bind the handlers, or when the handlers run?

Comment: let say there is one case: I have a DIV, initially its mousedown event is generating a print out a string in console. Then I setup up a button which is after clicked, the DIV's mousedown event becomes changing color and print string in console. And when mouseup, the DIV's mousedown event return to only print string

Comment: You can use a single function, and it can check a variable to determine whether to change the color. Clicking the button will change the value of the variable.