# Is it possible to attach a callback to the setting of an delegated event listener (.on())?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I want to use a class to select elements to receive delegated click event listeners. But I want to remove the class immediately after that.

This is what I had in mind:

```
docSelector // $(window.document)
.on('click touchstart', btnSelector, click[name])
.queue(function() {
        // remove class to prevent extra binding
        $(btnSelector).removeClass(btnSelector);
 });
```

I think it should be clear what I am trying to do, but I'm not sure `queue` even works for this kind of thing. I'm not super familiar with jQuery, but am working on someone else's code who uses it liberally. Thanks in advance.

In other words, I guess I'm looking for a generic method for tacking a callback on the end of chain.

Comment: Do you mean, after setting the event listener for whatever elements `btnSelector` refers to, you want to remove the class from some other elements so some other code does not add an event on them? If so you could just add a line after your `.on()` statement removing the classes: `$(".jc-click-"+name).removeClass("jc-click-"+name)`. Or do you mean you need to remove the class after the click listener has been triggered?

Comment: ah! this is it. I don't know why I didn't think of just expanding the click handler out into a function call where I can add whatever I need. Doh! Thank you!

Comment: JK - what I was thinking doesn't actually work. `btnSelector` and `clickSel` are actually the same selector string. And yes, I want to remove the class after the click handler has been set. But now I realize I can't do that, because the event delegation will need to the class there.

Comment: This is really a poor question on my part -- I should have thought this through further.

Answer (score 1):

[`queue`](https://api.jquery.com/queue/) function depends on [`dequeue`](https://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) call. If you need to remove the class ASAP, you should do it in the specified `click[name]` function handler.

Also [jQuery: more than one handler for same event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491718/jquery-more-than-one-handler-for-same-event)

> The handlers will execute in the order in which they were bound.
>
> As jQuery event model allows multiple handlers on one element,
>   therefore a later handler does not override an older handler.

You could do something like :

```
docSelector // $(window.document)
//Is executed first
.on('click touchstart', btnSelector, function(){
    // remove class to prevent extra binding
    var classSel = '.jc-click-' + name;
    $(classSel).removeClass(classSel);
})
//Is executed just after
.on('click touchstart', btnSelector, click[name]);
```

Comment: Yeah, there are just many, many click[name] handlers, structured differently.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear in my answer that btnSelector and classSel are basically the same. So I didn't actually need to chain anything, just need to add break click[name] out into a generic fn, and handle the class removal on the line after. Thanks for taking the time though.

Comment: JK - that isn't the solution. I spoke too soon. That would include the class removal in the click handler.