# Possible JQuery expand current binding?

Tags: jquery

It is possible to expand an existing binding?

```
/* Existing */
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
    console.log("exist");
});

/* Additional */
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
    console.log("ADD");
});
```

On `#btn` click it should log: `exist` and `ADD`

Comment: In Javascript and actually many different languages, you can execute more than a single command within a function, it's pretty neat

Comment: This will work fine, although note that it's not 'expanding' the existing event handler, but instead adding a new one. The effect will be what you require though

Comment: See similar question and answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491718/jquery-more-than-one-handler-for-same-event

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1Lf1pg59/